# Restore a jpg image from text file

Tags: data-recovery, adobe-photoshop, file-corruption

I have a corrupted/malformed image when playing around with notepad and the photos app in windows 10. Possibly I dragged the .jpg image into a text file and later the image got deleted accidentally. Now I only have the text file. I am not sure if the text file had any other data before the image was dragged into it.

I can't share the file because the picture is a bit private.

There is this part at the start of the file which is a bit readable

[image]

Please let me know if anything can be done to recover the image.

Comment: Looks like the header is intact.  Did you try renaming it to .jpg and see it will open?

Comment: @LawrenceC I did no luck.

Comment: If so then the file is corrupted and cannot be salvaged. Try to find it in the Recycle Bin.